How to use 128bit float and complex numbers in OpenCL/CUDA?
I need to use 128 bit floating point numbers and complex numbers in parallel GPU computing using OpenCL or CUDA.
Are there any ways to achieve this without implementing it yourself?
I looked at the OpenGL and CUDA specifications and found no float128 support there, is it really impossible for me to use float128 in them?
I tried to look for any libraries, but it seems that they do not exist, is that so?
At least I would like to be able to use float128, is it possible to achieve this?

There is AFAIK no standard support of 128-bit FP numbers on Nvidia GPUs. In fact, client GPUs are optimized of <=32-bit FP numbers and very slow for 64-bit ones. Server GPUs can compute 64-bit FP efficiently though. To get 128-bit ones, you need a kind of emulation which is generally very slow like >=32x time slower than 64-bit one (which is already generally >=32x times slower on client GPUs and >=2x on servers). Put it shortly: you should avoid that as much as possible for sake of performance and if you really need that, then try emulation.

@JérômeRichard, Well, that's very sad. Aren't there any third-party solutions for this?

By the way, the resulting error on 128-bit numbers with emulation should be significantly higher than what the IEEE standard specify (eg. dozens of ULPs). If you need 100% accurate IEEE 128-bit numbers, then the slow-down will be even higher than the one mentioned above.

It would probably be easier to emulate 128 bit or more fixed point arithmetic using 32 bit integer maths if that's a reasonable option.

float128 (and higher) is something of a minority interest. What is it that you are trying to do in CUDA that requires them? There may be other ways around your problem.

Last time I looked, I found this project. I did not test it but I guess the logic can be ported to OpenCL/CUDA and to 128-bit (from 64-bit) instead of 64-bit ones (from 32-bit). However, be aware that most of the time, 128-bit numbers are not really needed. You can often increase the numerical stability of algorithms so 64-bit is enough. 64-bit numbers can store the earth-moon distance with a precision <0.1µm which is insane and certainly far beyond the precision we can get from all measurement systems). Do you really need that?

@JérômeRichard They are sometimes handy for computing precise reference values that can be trusted in test cases that aim to get the right answer in double precision for very awkward numerical problems. Likewise for higher precision still - but you generally don't care about speed when computing a handful of test cases.

@MartinBrown, I am trying to draw a Mandelbrot set and as its zoom increases, double becomes very quickly missing, I need more numbers after the point.

You might be altogether better off using AVX vector code with FMA and pairs of carefully chosen doubles to represent the centre of the tile and its x & y range then.

I also think fixed-point arithmetic is the better choice because float128 wont be enough depending on the depth of the zoom. There exists a big num CUDA library (CGBN) which lets warps cooperate on big num operations, i.e. it makes available more parallelism at higher precision.

See also the comments below Increasing the float precision for plotting Mandelbrot fractal using GPU (which is somewhat of a duplicate but also unanswered and asked in the context of Python/Numba).

None of the modern GPUs/CPUs support FP128. The GPUs only have circuitry for FP32 and very limited to no support for FP64. Neither OpenCL nor CUDA support FP128.
You have to implement the format yourself, conversion and arithmetic emulated as a struct of 2 64-bit integers. Same for complex numbers.
I have super fast FP16<->FP32 conversion algorithms here, they are adaptable to FP64<->FP128. For the arithmetic you have to find a solution.
What do you even need 34 decimal digits for? Is there a way to get the same done with FP64? Quite often you can do numeric trickery to avoid digit extinction with lower precision formats.
Also, have a look at Posit formats. If your application only does arithmetic close to the number 1, 64-bit Posit is way more capable than FP64 and could be good enough.


I need to use 128 bit floating point numbers and complex numbers in parallel GPU computing using OpenCL or CUDA. Are there any ways to achieve this without implementing it yourself?

No. Not in 2024-Q3, not counting FPGA-s or SoC-s or brave hobbyists resuscitated Transputer fabrics workarounds for other, hardware-parallel, ways possible.

The answer is dedicated to WHY it is a bad idea to use FP-number representations in arithmetic methods, that help decide any critical thing.
Many safety-critical industries do not and must not degrade due to poorly handled ( or unhandled at all, like in many "fast"-CFD "solvers" ) numerical methods and similar cases, where number-representation decides success from failures ( nice pictures about physical non-sense are not reliable results in life-critical disciplines ).
Pictures may please uneducated eyes, yet if science stays serious about values ( indivisible from their respective RANGE of PRINCIPAL uncertainty - not only for measured values, even best known values of foundational const-s introduce RANGE of PRINCIPAL uncertainty ~ +/- 1E-8 ), many algo-s soon yield results like N +/- oo !

Knowing "WHY" is infinitely more valuable, than knowing "THAT" :
Prof. Pospisil, advisor to several US presidents, used to claim "Serious science creates understanding ( based on repeatable experiments ). That allows generalisations."

I am trying to draw a Mandelbrot set and as its zoom increases, double becomes very quickly missing, I need more numbers after the point.


By Claude Heiland-Allen - Own work, CC BY-SA 4.0,https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=47022590
Facts first :(a)Mandelbrot set is not a "picture" as we know it, it is an infinitely complex mathematical object, which has a surprisingly trivial, iterative formulation, yet problems ( as you noted ) start once we try to somehow create its visual ( simplified ) representation, the more as you try to "dive" deeper and deeper, as hardware-related number-representation constraints start to create problems for us, to still compute somehow meaningful values.
(b)As Kahn has proved in 2001, the Mandelbrot set is smoothly connected (!) in a topological sense, so attempts to "rasterise" its simplified visual presentation into 2D-grid creates more and more problems on finer and finer levels of detail ( further complicating need for reasonable number-representation, so problems already contained ad (a) grow even bigger ).
(c)As the Mandelbrot set is an abstract object, it does not have any physical world constraints ( like passing a Planck length or headbanging into the principal boundary of the Heisenberg's uncertainty principle ), so huge, principally infinite, depths of level of details cannot be avoided.
Good news :
Simplicity of your choice - using only the Mandelbrot set membership-detecting iterator, which tests an iterator-produced value against a preset "giveup"-threshold, you do not need anything more complicated, then ADD()-, SUB()- and MUL()- algebraical methods implemented ( to use any kind of number-representation of your further choice ... at this moment, you should have already realised, that as the float64 soon degrades, the same will float128 and a custom number-representation will be the only way forwards to "deeper" zooms in graphing the 2D-sections of the Mandelbrot set ).
No matter what custom-defined number representation you will opt in, the membership-detecting iterator just uses these simple calculations, derived from standard notation of iterative generator ( zn+1 = zn2 + c )  :
z_RE := c_RE + ( z_RE + z_IM ) * ( z_RE - z_IM )
z_IM := c_IM + ( z_RE * z_IM * 2 )

and test, if :
( z_RE * z_RE + z_IM * z_IM ) > a_giveup_threshold_SquaredCONST

So we need only :
8 registers ( instances of ( almost ) infinite precision storage - only [SPACE] is our limit here ), and
4 operations ( ADD, SUB, MUL, > ), composable from 64-bit, 32-bit or even 16-bit hardware uops on smart used bitfields.
For doing this, the math curriculum of first year of high school, Lyceum or secondary school, where polynomials were taught for even polynome-by-polynome divisions ( which we do not need here ), is all you need for creating a trivial or more sophisticated ( variable-length ) number-representation, that could be processed in parallel, smart-using SIMD instructions of choice ( even on GPU ).
Bad news :
Using good tools, for things they have been invented for, usually helps us getting the results in that problem-domain there. Using tool, which is good for something else than we need to solve, need not help us to solve our problem more easily.
This is the case with the O/P statement

"(...) use 128 bit floating point numbers and complex numbers in parallel GPU computing using OpenCL or CUDA."

GPU SM-engines, CUDA, OpenCL were designed to excel at delivering fast, trivial-mathematical-kernels executions, doing transformations over things like RGB 8-bit colorplanes ( texturing, local-smoothing et al ).
If we were to type this :

مطرقة ماسلو: "عندما تكون المطرقة هي الأداة الوحيدة التي تمتلكها، فجأة تصبح كل الأشياء تشبه المسمار..."

using Bulgarian, Sanskrit or similar keyboards, we would fail as miserably, as we will with trying to "enforce" GPU start working with Complex128 or Float128 values as efficiently, as it works with 4-bit ( in inference TPU-s ) or similarly fixed-bit-depth optimised on-board SM + memory hardware + programming-language transformers.
All that does not mean you cannot get ( almost ) infinitely deep views into Mandelbrot set sections.
You just will have to design a smart-code for { ADD, SUB, MUL, < }-operators for your new, custom-defined number-representation, that will not degenerate on deeper zooms.
All this is doable, using fixed- or even variable-length number-representation, even to get ported onto the COTS GPU-fabrics, yet also be aware that as you most probably will still resort to some kind of discrete coverage of points inside a zoomed-in 2D-section, the GPU will not boost performance as your expectations might be, as the thread-coherency will by definition soon explode your warp-wide threads out from "Coherent-scheduler"-mode, and threads will principally finish in divergent mode ( as their iterator "mileage" will vary a lot ) so the GPU SM scheduler will soon fallback into so called "Greedy-mode", where the hardware, optimised for latency masking, will perform awfully worse than for "Coherent-mode" warp-wide SIMD number-crunching ( Amdahl's Law and GPU latency-masking details matter, a lot ).
Bonus part :
My first Mandelbrot implementation and number-representation naive  experiments started some 40 years ago, on 8-bit vehicles Commodore C-128 ( 128 kB RAM was a luxurious space those days (!) ) and Sir Clive Sinclair's ZX Spectrum ( 48 kB RAM ), both using PAL-TV as display.
Today, using the syntax of :
ffplay -f  lavfi        \
       -fs -i mandelbrot \
       -vf "format=gbrp,split=4[a][b][c][d],[d]histogram=display_mode=0:level_height=244[dd],[a]waveform=m=1:d=0:r=0:c=7[aa],[b]waveform=m=0:d=0:r=0:c=7[bb],[c][aa]vstack[V],[bb][dd]vstack[V2],[V][V2]hstack"


we can do a lot more and reveal new levels of detail and demonstrate further problems :


How would one defend slowing down the computation process?
How did mathematically imprecise implementation "end"?
How will mathematically precise implementation "end" and why?
What arguments defend the structures, observed in orthogonal
histogram views, are more "properties" of projected, smoothly
connected (as proved above) topological structure, than artificial
artifacts emerging from chosen number-representation weaknesses?


While this seems like a good answer to the cited comment, it probably wont be of much value to someone finding "How to use 128bit float and complex numbers in OpenCL/CUDA?". And as there is already another answer about that aspect, editing the comment into the question (invalidating that answer) is also not a good option. I would propose migrating this answer to the older, unanswered question that I linked in a comment. There it would be more fitting.

Lol calm down. I just saw the negative score of this answer that you seem to have put some work into. I neither flagged nor voted on your answer so I have no idea how you get the idea I would be censoring you. I just thought a moment about why people might not upvote this answer (or even downvote it) and came to the conclusion that it has to come from the absence of the Mandelbrot zoom topic in the actual question. And because I would rather see it upvoted and I found that unanswered question I tried to communicate my thought to you. If you are fine with the current state of affairs so be it.

I wrote that editing the question to better fit your answer is not a good option. I did not write that one should not add answers to already answered questions.

Assuming that only a fraction of people interested in using 128b floating point arithmetic on GPUs is also interested in Mandelbrot zooms, a big part of these people wont be interested in most of your answer (which is fine by me, might be bad for the answer's score though). I'm not pressurizing you on removing this answer at all. All I'm saying is that if I would read this answer below that other question, I would upvote it.

@paleonix What did you consider to 've been an "editing the question ( to better fit your answer ) " ?

Basically editing in the additional information that OP offered in the comments. As long as there wasn't any answers of the original question, one could have edited it to be specifically about the Mandelbrott zoom (or asked OP to do so). The thing is that StackOverflow Q&As are not primarily aimed at helping the question author (which is a nice side-effect) but at presenting information to future readers. Therefore scoring of answers will depend on coherency between the question and the answer without regard for comments even if your answer was more helpful to OP.

Aha - by "editing in" @paleonix seem to meant "copy/paste 1:1 what O/P has specified". Yes, I copy/paste an important part of what the O/P was asking. That is common to address as close as possible the subject, that was asked. Even the professor saw this, before he posted "answer" to something else, than was asked ( O/P never expressed interest in computing numbers only in a close proximity of 1 ). Last but not least, the first about two decades of Community sponsored content here, was about answering O/P questions. If this gets changed, the future will tell us if it were a good move.

But OP's question is not about the Mandelbrot set. For better or worse you answered what you think OP's question should have been. The part of the answer that relates to the actual question is minuscule (should have been a comment).

No, OP's question IS about using 128bit number representation for computing ( Mandelbrot + in principle any numerical computing ).The answer is dedicated to WHY it is a bad idea to use FP-number representation in arithmetic methods, that help decide any critical thing. Pictures may please uneducated eyes, yet if science stays serious about values ( indivisible from their respective RANGE of PRINCIPAL uncertainty - not only for measured values, even best known values of foundational const-s introduce RANGE of PRINCIPAL uncertainty ~ +/- 1E-8 ), many algo-s soon yield results like N +/- oo ! Aha
